# How to select current dragging element?

Tags: jquery, html

In the below code while cloning the element it clones the previously added element. While dragging 2nd element it clones first element also.. totally 3 elements will appear. how to clone current div only ?.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mutharasum/cv0fvmej/)

```
   $(document).ready(function($) {
    var a=0;
    $("div[id^='product']").draggable({
        helper: function () {
            return $("<div class='dragger'></div>").append($(this).clone().append("<button>remove</button>"));
        }
    });

    $("#dropcombo").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {    
        a++;    
           $(this)
                .find("p")
                .text(a);
            var element = $('.ui-draggable-dragging');
            var currentDrop=$(this);
            return element.clone().appendTo(currentDrop);
        }
    });
    $(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();

    });
  });

<div id="product1" class="draggable">
    <h1>AA</h1>
</div>
<div id="product2" class="draggable">
    <h1>AA</h1>
</div>
<div id="product3" class="draggable">
    <h1>AA</h1>
</div>
<div id="product4" class="draggable">
    <h1>AA</h1>
</div>
<div id="dropcombo">
    <h3>Drop packages to buy</h3>
    <div> you have selected <p>0</p> packages</div>
    <img id="imgg" src="images/Packages.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to first read the documentation from [jquery draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#events)

then do help own by defining events for draggable. When a drag start and a drag stop in both case events are fired so first define these call back and then you need to manually operation with draggable event with your desired operation